# Converting scraped R data using readHTMLTable()

Tags: r

I'm trying to scrape this website http://www.hockeyfights.com/fightlog/ but having hard time putting the into a nice data frame. So far I have this:

```
> asdf <- htmlParse("http://www.hockeyfights.com/fightlog/1")
> asdf.asdf <- readHTMLTable(asdf)
```

Then I get this giant list. How do I convert this into a 2 column dataframe that has only player names (who were in a fight) with n rows (number of fights)?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. can you show some rows of the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the output you're after?

```
require(RCurl); require(XML)
asdf <- htmlParse("http://www.hockeyfights.com/fightlog/1")
asdf.asdf <- readHTMLTable(asdf)
```

First, make a table of each player and the count of fights they've been in...

```
# get variable with player names
one <- as.character(na.omit(asdf.asdf[[1]]$V3))
# get counts of how many times each name appears
two <- data.frame(table(one))
# remove non-name data
three <- two[two$one != 'Away / Home Player',]
# check
head(three)
 one Freq
1  Aaron Volpatti    1
3  Brandon Bollig    1
4     Brian Boyle    1
5 Brian McGrattan    1
6      Chris Neil    2
7  Colin Greening    1
```

Second, make a table of who is in each fight...

```
# make data frame of pairs by subsetting the vector of names
four <- data.frame(away = one[seq(2, length(one), 3)],
                   home = one[seq(3, length(one), 3)])
# check
head(four)
            away            home
1    Brian Boyle     Zdeno Chara
2    Tom Sestito      Chris Neil
3     Dale Weise Mark Borowiecki
4 Brandon Bollig Brian McGrattan
5 Scott Hartnell     Eric Brewer
6 Colin Greening  Aaron Volpatti
```

Comment: Yes. But may I ask one more thing? How would you put the names in every other column. So, if Aaron Volpatti and Brandon Bollig were in a fight, Volpatti would be in col1, Bollig would be in col2. Followed by Dillon in col1, McGrattan in col2. Thanks for the help!